# Displaying JSON output from an API call in Ruby using VScode

Tags: ruby, api, zoho

For context, I'm someone with zero experience in Ruby - I just asked my Senior Dev to copy-paste me some of his Ruby code so I could try to work with some APIs that he ended up putting off because he was too busy.

So I'm using an API wrapper called `zoho_hub`, used as a wrapper for Zoho APIs (https://github.com/rikas/zoho_hub/blob/master/README.md).

My IDE is VSCode.

I execute the entire length of the code, and I'm faced with this:

`[Done] exited with code=0 in 1.26 seconds`

The API is supposed to return a paginated list of records, but I don't see anything outputted in VSCode, despite the fact that no error is being reflected. The last 2 lines of my code are:

```
ZohoHub.connection.get 'Leads'
p "testing"
```

I use the dummy string "testing" to make sure that it's being executed up till the very end, and it does get printed.

This has been baffling me for hours now - is my response actually being outputted somewhere, and I just can't see it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby does not print anything unless you tell it to. For debugging there is a pretty printing method available called `pp`, which is decent for trying to print structured data.

In this case, if you want to output the records that your `get` method returns, you would do:

```
pp ZohoHub.connection.get 'Leads'
```

To get the next page you can look at [the source code](https://github.com/rikas/zoho_hub/blob/master/lib/zoho_hub/connection.rb), and you will see the `get` request has an additional Hash parameter.

```
def get(path, params = {})
```

Then you have to read [the Zoho API documentation for get](https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/get-records.html), and you will see that the page is requested using the `page` param.

Therefore we can finally piece it together:

```
pp ZohoHub.connection.get('Leads', page: NNN)
```

Where `NNN` is the number of the page you want to request.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Since it looks like my response is paginated - would you also know how to scroll through the pages using `pp`? Atm it only seems to be displaying page 1.

Comment: See my edits to the answer. It is not tested code, but this is how I assume it should work based on the docs and source code. Give it a try.